# BOTH available-old & available missing from dpkg - "dpkg: error: failed to open package info file `/var/lib/dpkg/available' for reading"

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, dpkg

Issue : Many threads try to solve the broken packages problem using the options as below. However my main problem is that BOTH the available & available-old do not exist . I have no clue how I ended up deleting them(if it wasnt because of a corrupt package, instead)

```
sudo dpkg --clear-avail && sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a 
ekta@superwomen:~$ sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bluez bluez-alsa bluez-cups bluez-gstreamer cython dpkg dpkg-dev firefox
  firefox-globalmenu firefox-locale-en flashplugin-installer
  gnome-settings-daemon libbluetooth3 libdpkg-perl liblcms2-2 thunderbird
  thunderbird-gnome-support thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-us
  unity-greeter
20 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/72.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 15.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error: failed to open package info file `/var/lib/dpkg/available' for reading: No such file or directory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)


sudo do-release-upgrade

dpkg: error: failed to open package info file `/var/lib/dpkg/available' for reading: No such file or directory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)


--- from update manager ---
    installArchives() failed: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
    perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
        are supported and installed on your system.
    perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
    locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
    Preconfiguring packages ...
    perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
    perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
        are supported and installed on your system.
    perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
    locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
    Preconfiguring packages ...
    perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
    perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
        are supported and installed on your system.
    perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
    locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
    Preconfiguring packages ...
    perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
    perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = (unset),
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_IN.ISO8859-1"
        are supported and installed on your system.
    perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
    locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
    locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
    Preconfiguring packages ...
    dpkg: error: failed to open package info file `/var/lib/dpkg/available' for reading: No such file or directory
```

dpkg: error: failed to open package info file `/var/lib/dpkg/available' for reading: No such file or directory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

I am on ubuntu 12.04 LTS & here's the contents of /var/lib/dpkg

```
ekta@superwomen:/var/lib/dpkg$ ls -l 
total 9932
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Apr 29 15:23 alternatives
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  372736 May  4 20:08 info
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root       0 May  4 22:31 lock
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Apr 13  2012 parts
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1975559 May  4 22:32 status
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1947927 May  4 21:39 status-bad
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1947932 May  4 20:48 status-old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1947932 May  4 21:48 status_ekta
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1948728 May  4 20:48 status~
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 Apr 29 15:23 triggers
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    4096 May  4 21:39 updates
```

status_ekta is a manually created backup & status-bad reflects that I did this manipulation to the "main" status file before taking the backup (in a different folder)  . Status file, thus should be fine.

I also tried purge, autoremove - which basically removed the corrupt packages, but does not solve the main problem of not having the "list" of available packages.

**My question :**

**1.** What does the available file have anyway ? can I update this manually using dpkg -l somehow?

**2.** How do I solve this without complete re-install, and if there are stable alternatives to apt-get (apt-get is ONLY for dpkg I assume ?) What else will I have to live without, if I do not fix this ?

I also deselected the ppa repos from update manager & selected the "Main Server" , as a part of Canonical troubleshooting [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure), but it did not help.

Here's what I have in my "status" file -

```
ekta@superwomen:/var/lib/dpkg$ cat status | grep "Status:" | sort -u 
Status: deinstall ok config-files
Status: install ok installed
```

Answer (score 1):

Just boot from Ubuntu live disk and copy the `/var/lib/dpkg/available` file to it's corresponding path in the partition where Ubuntu is actually installed.

- Boot from Ubuntu live disk and the click on try Ubuntu option on startup.
- Now openup the terminal by pressing ctrl+Alt+T.

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt        # Where /dev/sdaX is your installed Ubuntu's partition
  sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available /mnt/var/lib/dpkg
  ```
- After the above operation, boot from your Hard-disk. Now it will work.

Comment: `/dev/sda1` is your root partition. So replace `/dev/sdaX` in the above answer with `/dev/sda1`